# Message: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, mysqli

I have a connection error...

Im using an API Restful for connect my Android App with DataBase(MySql)

api.php:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'funciones.php';
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$db = new mysqli("XX.XXX.XXX.XXX", "user_BD", "pass_BD", "name_BD");
.
.
.

$app->get("/sp_login_principal/:user/:pass", function($user,$pass) use($db, $app) {
    // sleep(3);
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE 
                            user =  '".$user."' 
***line 63:***                  AND password= '".$pass."' ;");

    $usuarios = array();
    while ($fila = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $usuarios[] = $fila;
    }
     utf8_encode_deep($usuarios);
    echo json_encode($usuarios);
});
```

"***line 63:***" it's only a commet, is not really in the code.

When i use the next url to call the select:

http://XXXX.000webhostapp.com/eldo/slim/api.php/sp_login_principal/useraname/passxxxx

I have the next error:

*

```
Slim Application Error
The application could not run because of the following error:
Details
Type: ErrorException
Code: 2
Message: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli
File: /storage/XXX/XXX/XXXXXXX/public_html/eldo/slim/api.php
Line: 63
Trace
#0 [internal function]: Slim\Slim::handleErrors(2, 'mysqli::query()...', '/storage/XXXX/2...', 63, Array)
#1 /storage/XXXX/XXX/XXXXXXX/public_html/eldo/slim/api.php(63): mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM u...')
#2 [internal function]: {closure}('username', 'passxxxx')
#3 /storage/XXX/XXX/XXXXXX/public_html/eldo/slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(468): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#4 /storage/XXX/XXX/XXXXXX/public_html/eldo/slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php(1357): Slim\Route->dispatch()
#5 /storage/XXX/XXX/XXXXXX/public_html/eldo/slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/Flash.php(85): Slim\Slim->call()
#6 /storage/XXX/XXX/XXXXXX/public_html/eldo/slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/MethodOverride.php(92): Slim\Middleware\Flash->call()
#7 /storage/XXX/XXX/XXXXXX/public_html/eldo/slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/PrettyExceptions.php(67): Slim\Middleware\MethodOverride->call()
#8 /storage/XXX/XXX/XXXXXX/public_html/eldo/slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php(1302): Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions->call()
#9 /storage/XXX/XXX/XXXXXX/public_html/eldo/slim/api.php(1164): Slim\Slim->run()
#10 {main}
```

*

I think the error is in the server file, because i used the same code on another server withoud problems.

Thanks!

Comment: See what `$query` is, check it for errors (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). This is open to SQL injections parameterize the query. Passwords also should be hashed.

Comment: Thanks!!! 
Mi error was:

Warning</b>:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out in
Connect failed: Connection timed out

The problem is that i have mi Database in another server. I migrated some tables in the same server and Works fine! 

The another DataBase Server not allow external connections...